# No module named 'imagenet_utils' for Jupyter but exists on Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, keras

```
import numpy as np
import os
import time
from vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing import image
from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import merge, Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from keras.models import load_model
```

I was running a vgg model in my pc using Spyder everything was working fine, but when I tried running the code in Jupyter for using cloud gpu I got the following error:

```
 >>>>>
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-4398e37e021e> in <module>()
----> 1 from imagenet_utils import preprocess_input, decode_predictions

ImportError: No module named 'imagenet_utils'<<<
```

Why do I have this when its working fine in another IDE quite fine? I am using Jupyter for training the model in cloud using Floyd web service.

Comment: you sure you run spyder & jupyter in the same (virtual) environment?

Comment: @desertnaut yes I opened anaconda choose the correct environment and ran it still have same issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try importing it like:

```
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_prediction
```

This is the standard way according to the Keras Applications [doc page](https://keras.io/applications/). More reference about Keras Applications can be found there also.

*Note:* Be aware that it is `decode_prediction` and not `decode_predictions` in plural.

Comment: ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-71f1b7d87909> in <module>()
----> 1 from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input,decode_prediction

ImportError: cannot import name 'decode_prediction'

Comment: preprocessing_input is working not decode_prediction

Comment: @sachsom yikes, it does have one! It is prediction (in singluar) not plural (predictionS) :) sorry my bad. I am sure it works now, updated my answer.

Comment: yes it works thankyou, sir. if you don't mind can you explain why this happens

Comment: @sachsom glad I could help :) there are several things that may cause this. I suspect that your `imagenet_utils` library may not be installed for your jupyter as your spyder one has. Also, some IDEs (like spyder) automatically import and know several libraries you use by default. One example is that in Spyder you may omit the `import numpy` line as spyder by default imports it. This can cause compatibility issues when running in other places outside an IDE. That is why I suggest you **always try your code on a terminal** to make sure things like these dont happen.

Comment: @sachsom also, the less you depend on external libraries the better. If Keras already has a `decode_prediction` method it is better to chose that over any other external option. Some blogs give Keras examples using the `imagenet_utils` package, but that doesn't mean it is the *only* way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

As opposed to the older versions of keras (or tensorflow), you will need to be model-specific while importing imagenet_utils functions preprocess_input and decode_predictions.

For example, if you're working with Tensorflow 2 and working with ResNet50, you will have to do it in following manner

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import decode_predictions, preprocess_input
```

In this case it is decode_predictions (plural) and not decode_prediction. Similar for VGG16 and other models

Answer (score 1):

Try to import:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import decode_predictions
```